# Choosing k positions among n with no more distance d each other

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

Let $\binom{n}{k}_{<d}$ the number of combinations of k elements among [1,n] with constrained spacing :

no element can be at distance d or more from its successor.

$$\binom{n}{k}_{<d} = \sum_j (-1)^j \binom{k-1}{j}\binom{n-dj}{k} $$

How to prove this?

First, I simply thought the identity means that all $\binom{n}{k}$ - (1 case at distance d) - (2 cases) - (3 cases)- ...

But there is $(-1)^j$ term, so that it is not as intuitive as I expected.

Comment: Use the in-and-out formula a.k.a. inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: If $E$ is the set of all $k$-combinations from $[n]$ and $E_i$ is the set of just those $k$-combinations where the $i^\text{th}$ gap is at least $d$, you want to count the elements in the set $E\setminus(E_1\cup E_2\cup\cdots\cup E_{k-1})$.

Comment: Thank you. I confused what the j means exactly. It was not just "number" but also "position".

Comment: $$|E\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}E_i|=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\sum_{J\in\binom{[k-1]}{j}}|\bigcap_{i\in J}E_i|$$ where $[k-1]=\{1,2,\dots,k-1\}$, $\binom{[k-1]}{j}=\{J\subseteq[k-1]:|J|=j\}$, and $\bigcap_{i\in\varnothing}E_i=E$.